# CSS responsive menu with logo

Tags: css, responsive-design, menu

I am trying to make responsive menu. Logo is on the left and menu on the right. Is there a way to detect when menu has touched the logo when page width goes small so I could show menu icon (currently hidden) and make menu vertical below the logo?

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  float: right;
}

.topnav svg {
  color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}



.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="logo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M16 132h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V76c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16C7.163 60 0 67.163 0 76v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16z"></path></svg>
      </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Usually people just use media query to handle this, you can figure out the width of the media query fairly easily. You could also calculate the sum of the width of your menu and the width of the logo then compare it to the width of the browser but why do that when you can easily solve this with media query

Comment: Here is an example how you would use media-queries to achieve your goal: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/yv9Lxjo4/18/).

Comment: But then I need to calculate width of the logo.